# Is there any `setvirtcol()`?

Tags: vimscript, cursor-movement

I'm looking for a way to precisely set the cursor position given a virtual column.

Is there only `:exe "normal! ".vcol."|"`?

NB: I need virtual columns as they're the only thing that I'm able to compute correctly in a context where there are multi-byte characters that occupy only one column, and tab characters that spawns over several columns.

Regarding the context, I should be more explicit. If I'm looking for a function, it's partly out of curiosity, partly to avoid translating a tuple of coordinates (that I already have thanks to `getpos(a_mark)`) into something else, partly for style consistency: I'm trying to fix/enhance a plugin where I try to use functions. This implies I cannot expect something as the virtual editing mode to be in a state or in another: plugins need to work whatever the end-user choose for her/his vim options. Yet, it's true I could change it momentarily and restore it in a `finally` statement.

Also, I'm not in the general case where I may end up in the middle of a tabulation. Any position, I want to jump to, is accessible without `'virtualedit'` being set. The (computed) position matches a placeholder in an expanded and re-indented code snippet.

Comment: I don't often use virtual columns so it might be a dumb comment but can't you do what you want with [`:h setpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setpos%28%29) and use the `off` entry of the list taken as parameter?

Comment: According to the documentation, `"off"` relates to virtualedit mode, which is not my situation.

Comment: Ok I thought `virtualedit` was mandatory to use virtual columns, my bad :)

Comment: No. It's unrelated. In `\t/*«»*/ if () {`, `getcursorpos()` returns `[0, 2, 14, 0, 19]` when the cursor is on the `(`. The byte index is 14, but the actual (virtual...) column is 19 -- with `&ts==8`

Comment: I'm with @statox. You need to use `virtualedit` to position the cursor in a virtual column. If I have `ts=4` and the cursor is somewhere in a line starting with a tab,  `2|` will not put the cursor in column 2. It will end up in column 4. OTOH, if I first do `:set virtualedit=all` then it _will_ go to column 2.

Comment: I should have stated my context more explicitly. I'm trying to fix a plugin that may be used by anybody with any possible setting. This means I cannot expect options to be a in certain state. The easiest solution for me would have been "tabs users cannot use my plugin"... Here however, I must admit I could set `virtualedit` momentarily. I've to think about that.

Comment: Also, positions I want to jump to _exist_: it's to a placeholder that gets replaced by the cursor after a multi-lines snippet is being inserted, interpreted, and reindented.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I read an unambiguous question and provided a straightforward answer for it. Q: _[How do I] precisely set cursor to a virtual col?_ A: `ve=all | call cursor(...)`. You're saying that's not what you really want to know? If there is missing context or additional details/requirements shouldn't you update the question rather than comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Tab example, let's say my line number 10 starts with a tab character (denoted by `>` and `-` for each of the three virtual columns that follow):

```
10: >---foo
```

This will place the cursor in (virtual) column 3:

```
set virtualedit=all
call cursor([10, 1, 2])
```

The list is `[lnum, col, off]`. `lnum` is line number. `col` is non virtual column and `off` is offset beyond `col` (this is the secret sauce to get to a virtual column).

Result:

```
10: >---foo
      ^
      |_____ cursor here
```

Note that without the `virtualedit` setting the cursor would be placed in column 1.

---

*My first submission used `setpos()` instead until I realized that `cursor()` is more straightforward...*

```
call setpos(".", [0, 10, 1, 2])
```

`"."` means "set cursor position" (as opposed to a mark). The list is `[bufnum, lnum, col, off]`. A `bufnum` value of 0 indicates current buffer. The rest is identical to the parameters for `cursor()`.

Comment: While it's not exactly what I'm looking for, it gives me a strong hint why virtual columns are ignored by these functions when we are not in virtual editing mode. Thanks.

Comment: I think that what @LucHermitte is trying to do is: given the input `5`, place the cursor on the `f`  He’s not trying to find a way to place the cursor on “column” 3. (That’s what he means by “The places that I want to jump to *exist*”)

Comment: @Rich, it's indeed the case. B Layer wrote his (her?) answer before I provide more details on my exact use case.

Comment: @LucHermitte Ah, I didn’t notice the times (and dates!) on things.

Comment: Thanks @LucHermitte,  I'm glad it was helpful if somewhat off the mark. I appreciate the accept/vote.